# broken upload resume using youtube sdk

Tags: .net, youtube, youtube-api

Is it possible to resume a broken upload using Google data api for .net? I have downloaded the youtube sdk from [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/)

Answer (score 0):

[This code sample](https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/samples/YouTubeUploader/YouTubeUploader/YouTubeUploader.cs), which is packaged as part of the .NET GData client library, includes an example of using the Resumable Uploads flow.

Comment: we are experiencing an issue with Resumable Uploads for .NET . When will you release a Resumable Uploads sample for .NET V3 ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think this is only Upload a Video sample but our problem is, whenever i try upload my large size videos, they are waiting on "processing" on Youtube and never publish.. I am using this sample https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis/Apis/%5BMedia%5D/Upload/ResumableUpload.cs but i am having this "processing" issue. I was using Resumable Uploads for V2 and it was perfect. I think i should use Resumable Uploads for uploading large files. Have you ever had this "processing" issue before?

Comment: I think i have to use Resumable Uploads sample for large videos. I have seen Resumable Upload sample for PHP. Will you provide a Resumable Upload sample for .NET? It will be very useful for all .NET developer. Thank you.

Comment: You might be running into https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5700

Comment: Yes, i have the same issue. Thank you for your answer. I will be waiting for the solution.

Comment: I just checked the link again you said you fixed the issue. Did you update your sample codes on the website?